# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET API method to convert shapefile to ArcGIS feature set?

Tags: c#, geometry, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net, arcgis-10.4

Could anyone please let me know is there any ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET API method to convert a shapefile to ArcGIS feature set object?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by convert to feature set (why do you want to do this). If you just want to open and display a shapefile, see this sample http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=953a530ada30477d95cc69e788268bc9

Comment: Or this sample might be more up to date https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/html/8fe405cf-fbb4-4644-964f-0dae4ef50900.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply @KHibma. Actually I'm planning to make use of only Geometry operations in the ArcGIS Runtime to find intersection or distance of different Geometries which are currently contained in a shape file. So I'm looking for a method which would convert the given shape file into a feature set object from which ArcGIS geometries can be extracted to input them to any Geometry operation method.